# Spark SQL fails with "SQLCODE: <-25>:<Input encountered after end of query>" on intersystems cache DB JDBC read

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, intersystems-cache, intersystems

I am trying to connect to Intersystems Cache DB from databricks using spark JDBC reader API. Though I am able to connect , list columns for tables and run count on tables, I am not able to display data or process data . While displaying data for just a simple SELECT sql , I am getting below error :

```
 java.sql.SQLException: [SQLCODE: <-25>:<Input encountered after end of query>] --> Input (IDENTIFIER) encountered after end of query
```

I am using JDBC driver from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intersystems/cache-jdbc

Code:

```
df= spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:Cache://<IP>:<Port>/<NameSpace>”) \
    .option("query", “select some_column from schema.table”) \
    .option("user”,<user>) \
    .option("password”,<pwd>) \
    .option('driver','com.intersys.jdbc.CacheDriver') \
    .load()
df.columns # This works
df.count() # This works
df.show() # This throws error
```